# Javascript not running when i bring html content from Api with Vue

Tags: jquery, vue.js, axios

I'm having a modal (bootstrap) where i'm trying to populate the content onclick of the user. I have multiple products, each on click should load the product details quick view.

So my HTML looks like this :

```
<li class="">
   <a data-toggle="modal" v-on:click="loadProduct(<?=$pop->id?>, '<?=$language?>')" data-target="#productModal"  title="Quick View" class="quick-view modal-view detail-link" href="#">
   <span class="ti-plus"></span>
   </a>
</li>
```

My modal HTML code looks like this :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="productModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal__container" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span>&times;</span></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <div id="modalProduct" class="">
                      <div class="modalContentTrigger">
                          <div v-if="modalLoading" class="text-center" style="color:#ccc">
                              <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div v-if="!modalLoading">
                              <div v-html="modalContent"></div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I'm trying to bring the HTML content through an API call and fill the modalContent. Here is my vue function combined with AXios:

```
axios.post(vm.baseUrl + '/api/loadProduct', { productId: productId, language:language })
                      .then(function(response){
                        vm.modalContent = response.data;
                        vm.modalLoading = false;
                });
```

The content of the modal is populated very correct and i see the HTML inside the modal, but whatever javascript is inside, it is not working.
For example a simple `<div id='mydiv' onClick='alert("hello");'>test</div>` that is brought from the API is not triggering on click. If i put the same code in a static HTML it the trigger click works perfectly.

I'm using VUE2/AXIOS for the above code.

I'm tried even using Jquery to access the selector like this but it's not working again :

```
$("#mydiv").click(function(){alert('hello');});
```

So what am I doing wrong and the content loaded dynamically inside the modal is not java script friendly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR

```
$("body").on("click","#mydiv", function(){alert('hello');});
```

---

Vue isn't designed to be used this way. It's uncommon for an API to return raw HTML too. Vue won't parse the Javascript inside template. In fact if you try to include a script tag in any Vue template, you would get this error:

> Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI.
>   Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as
>   , as they will not be parsed.

If you can, avoid using `v-html`, change the API response so that it returns only the data needed for you to build the HTML, instead of the entire raw HTML. And you use the data inside Vue template.

But if you can't, you can continue to try to use jquery to listen to the click event.

`$("#mydiv").click(function(){alert('hello');});` doesn't work probably because this line is executed before `#mydiv` is created.

This should work for you:

```
$("body").on("click","#mydiv", function(){alert('hello');});
```

This listens to click event for `body` , and execute the click callback if the click target is `#mydiv`.